# Dropping first part of multi-indexed df based on event

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    (
        {
            "foo": ["1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2"],
            "bar": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4"],
            "info": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
            "event": [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        }
    )
)
# set multiindex
df.set_index(["foo", "bar"], inplace=True)

print(df)
         info  event
foo bar
1   1       1      0
    2       2      0
    3       3      1
    4       4      0
2   1       5      0
    2       6      1
    3       7      0
    4       8      0
```

I would like to slice the dataframe only to retain rows after event == 1:

| foo | bar | values | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 | 0 |

The sampling frequency is high enough that I can drop the 1's rows but would prefer to keep them if possible.

Comment: What output are you trying to get?

Comment: The table that's there. It drops first 2 in foo:1 and first 1 in foo:2

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```py
# Get relevant indices
index_of_first_event = df.loc[("1", "1"):, "event"].eq(1).idxmax()
last_index_of_first_sub_dataframe = ("1", str(df.loc[("1", ), :].shape[0]))
index_of_second_event = df.loc[("2", "1"):, "event"].eq(1).idxmax()

# Get new dataframe
new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.loc[index_of_first_event:last_index_of_first_sub_dataframe, :],
        df.loc[index_of_second_event:, :],
    ]
)

print(new_df)
# Output
         info  event
foo bar
1   3       3      1
    4       4      0
2   2       6      1
    3       7      0
    4       8      0
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

```
1.Mapped 0->na
2.Back-filled the event column
3.Dropped all 1's
```